# Long words in multicols list

Tags: lists, enumerate, multicol

I'm creating a list in 2 columns. I used the following code

```
\begin{multicols}{2}
    \begin{enumerate}[font=\bfseries,noitemsep]
        \item Cianotoxina(s) (\textit{Cyanotoxins(s)})
        \item Cilindrospermopsina(s) (\textit{Cylindrospermopsin(s)})
        \item Microcistina(s) (\textit{Microcystin(s)})
        \item Biodegradação (\textit{Biodegradation})
        \item Degradação (\textit{Degradation})
        \item Lago Paranoá (\textit{Paranoá Lake})
        \item Microbiota (\textit{Microbiota})
        \item Microbiota Bacteriana (\textit{Bacterial Microbiota})
    \end{enumerate}
\end{multicols}
```

In the 2nd item I'm getting a problem

[image]

How can I let LaTeX makes an automatical linebreak in lists with long words like this?

EDIT:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[brazil]{babel}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage[none]{hyphenat}
\begin{document}
    \begin{multicols}{2}
        \begin{enumerate}[font=\bfseries,noitemsep]
            \item Cianotoxina(s) (\textit{Cyanotoxins(s)})
            \item Cilindrospermopsina(s) (\textit{Cylindrospermopsin(s)})
            \item Microcistina(s) (\textit{Microcystin(s)})
            \item Biodegradação (\textit{Biodegradation})
            \item Degradação (\textit{Degradation})
            \item Lago Paranoá (\textit{Paranoá Lake})
            \item Microbiota (\textit{Microbiota})
            \item Microbiota Bacteriana (\textit{Bacterial Microbiota})
        \end{enumerate}
    \end{multicols}
\end{document}
```

I'd like to have in item 2 something like:

2. Cilindrospermopsina(s)

*(Cylindrospermopsin(s))*

3. ...
4. ...

EDIT 2:
I did it manually

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[brazil]{babel}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage[none]{hyphenat}
\begin{document}
\begin{multicols}{2}
    \begin{enumerate}[font=\bfseries,noitemsep]
        \item Cianotoxina(s) (\textit{Cyanotoxins(s)})
        \item Cilindrospermopsina(s) \\(\textit{Cylindrospermopsin(s)})
        \item Microcistina(s) (\textit{Microcystin(s)})
        \item Biodegradação (\textit{Biodegradation})
        \item Degradação (\textit{Degradation})
        \item Lago Paranoá (\textit{Paranoá Lake})
        \item Microbiota (\textit{Microbiota})
        \item Microbiota Bacteriana (\textit{Bacterial Microbiota})
    \end{enumerate}
\end{multicols}
\end{document}
```

[image]

There's a way to do it automatically?

Comment: Please tell us which document class you use, which font size you employ, and which packages are loaded in the preamble. Please also tell us which language settings, if any, were chosen. Finally, at which points should the long word "Cylindrospermopsin" be breakable? I would guess "Cylindro-spermo-psin", but I'm not a specialist in your field...

Comment: In fact, please put your code fragment into a minimal compilable document that shows the problem.  If I paste your code into `article` class, the second line hyphenates (with or without `babel`).  So you need to show exactly what you are doing to get the result you show.

Comment: Thanks for editing your posting and providing some additional information. Quick question: What do you think is achieved by `\usepackage[none]{hyphenat}`?

Comment: @Mico avoid hyphenation. Actually, I want a newline with whole word. I don't want to break in syllables

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Be default, the contents of a `multicols` environment are typeset in fully-justified mode; it would appear that this is not what you want in your example. I therefore suggest you provide a `\raggedright` directive immediately after `\begin{multicols}{2}` (and before `\begin{enumerate}...`).

A code snippet:

```
\begin{document}
    \begin{multicols}{2}
    \raggedright % <--- new
        \begin{enumerate}[font=\bfseries,noitemsep]
            \item Cianotoxina(s) \dots
```

A full MWE:

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[brazil]{babel}
\usepackage{multicol,enumitem,geometry}
\usepackage[none]{hyphenat}
\begin{document}
    \begin{multicols}{2}
    \raggedright
        \begin{enumerate}[font=\bfseries,noitemsep]
            \item Cianotoxina(s) 
                  (\textit{Cyanotoxins(s)})
            \item Cilindrospermopsina(s) 
                  (\textit{Cylindrospermopsin(s)})
            \item Microcistina(s) 
                  (\textit{Microcystin(s)})
            \item Biodegradação (\textit{Biodegradation})
            \item Degradação (\textit{Degradation})
            \item Lago Paranoá (\textit{Paranoá Lake})
            \item Microbiota (\textit{Microbiota})
            \item Microbiota Bacteriana 
                  (\textit{Bacterial Microbiota})
        \end{enumerate}
    \end{multicols}
\end{document}
```